# How can I reduce floating-point error in a cubic equation solver?

Tags: fortran, precision, scientific-computing

I'm using the following algorithm to solve a cubic polynomial equation (x^3 + a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0):

```
function find_roots(a, b, c, lower_bound, upper_bound)
    implicit none
    real*8, intent(in) :: a, b, c, lower_bound, upper_bound
    real*8 :: find_roots
    real*8 :: Q, R, theta, x, Au, Bu
    integer :: i, iter

    Q = (a**2 - 3.D0*b)/9.D0
    R = (2.D0*a**3 - 9.D0*a*b + 27.D0*c)/54.D0

    !If roots are all real, get root in range
    if (R**2.lt.Q**3) then
        iter = 0
        theta = acos(R/sqrt(Q**3))
        !print *, "theta = ", theta
        do i=-1,1
            iter = iter+1
            x = -2.D0*sqrt(Q)*cos((theta + dble(i)*PI*2.D0)/3.D0)-a/3.D0
            !print *, "iter = ", iter, "root = ", x
            if ((x.ge.lower_bound).and.(x.le.upper_bound)) then
                find_roots = x
                return
            end if
        end do
    !Otherwise, two imaginary roots and one real root, return real root
    else
        Au = -sign(1.D0, R)*(abs(R)+sqrt(R**2-Q**3))**(1.D0/3.D0)
        if (Au.eq.0.D0) then
            Bu = 0.D0
        else
            Bu = Q/Au
        end if
        find_roots = (Au+Bu)-a/3.D0
        return
    end if

end function find_roots
```

Now it turns out that it can be shown analytically that a cubic equation with the following inputs:

```
    Q0 = 1.D0
    alpha = 1.D-2
    dt = 0.00001D0
    Y = 1000000.D0

    find_roots(-(2.D0*Q0+Y), &
               -(alpha-Q0**2-2.D0*Y*Q0+dt/2.D0*alpha), &
               (dt/2.D0*alpha*Q0+Y*alpha-Y*Q0**2), &
               Q0-sqrt(alpha), &
               Q0+sqrt(alpha)))
```

MUST have a root between Q0+sqrt(alpha) and Q0-sqrt(alpha). This is a mathematical certainty. However, the function as called above will return 0, not the correct root, due to floating-point error, since the required result is very close to Q0+sqrt(alpha). I've confirmed this by creating a new function which uses quadruple precision. Unfortunately, I can't just always use quadruple precision since this function will be called billions of times and is a performance bottleneck.

So my question is, are there any general ways I could re-write this code to reduce these precision errors, while also maintaining the performance? I tried using the algorithm suggested by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions), but the problem actually got worse.

Comment: I tried your example using 32-bit and 64-bit FTN95 compiler. 32-bit gets a root value, but for 64-bit, "theta" is a different reported value ( 3.14159213354140 vs 3.141592134182251) resulting in no root calculated in range. R and Q are not significantly different so what is happening with acos ? ( R/sqrt(Q**3) = -1 could be the problem )

Comment: actually R/sqrt(Q**3) = -0.999999999999865 and acos is significantly different for 32-bit and 64-bit. I don't know why but it looks more than rounding !

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/algebra/algebra-ii/factoring-polynomials/sum-or-difference-of-cubes
This should reduce rounding error.
Likewise, you should be able to find a much better grouping of terms, where you don't make the compiler guess what you want,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method
alpha-Q0**2-2.D0*Y*Q0+dt/2.D0*alpha /= (alpha+alpha*.5*dt)-Q0*(Q0+2*Y)
You might argue that any good optimizer should know what to do with .5dt vs. dt/2. ifort considers that a part of -no-prec-div even though it can't change roundoff.
It's up to you whether you choose single precision constants for readability after checking to make sure that the promotion rules cause them to promote exactly to double.  It seems particularly bad style to depend on f77 D0 suffix to choose the same data type as the never-standard real*8; no doubt it does if your compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: As to the choice of (alpha + (alpha*.5)*dt) vs. alpha*(1+.5*dt) : when not considering the other term, the first is clearly better; it will have no intermediate roundoff error if done by fma instruction.  Another possibility is (alpha*(Y+.5*dt)-Q0)*Q0*(Q0+2*Y)  which may work better in the case dt>2 and Q0 close to alpha*(Y+.5*dt)

Comment: In that other expression, you may need to test or analyze several possibilities, but you should choose a better baseline than what you quote, e.g. Q0*(((dt*.5)*alpha)-Y*Q0)+Y*alpha.  Note that some of the care you take with parens will be ruined by ifort default options; you need options like -protect-parens, or with gfortran, avoid -ffast-math for this procedure.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. However, I don't quite understand how using the sum and difference of cubes or Horner's method will help here. Are you just generally suggesting that I should try a number of different factorisations?

I am using ifort so your discussion of different compiler options was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the accuracy of your calculations, either the calculation of a,b,c or the find_roots function estimates.

I used the a,b,c that are calculated and found that your lower_bound and upper_bound were better estimates of the roots.

I then modified the bounds to be +/- sqrt(alpha)*1.1 so that the range test would work for 64-bit.
I also simplified constants that promote exactly to double.

Finally I compared your estimate of the root to the fn (0.9d0) and fn (1.1d0), which shows the find_roots function does not work for the a,b,c provided.

You should check your references for the error or it may just be the approach fails when acos (+/- 1.0 ) is used.

The program I used to test this with lots of prints is:

```
 real*8 function find_roots (a, b, c, lower_bound, upper_bound)
    implicit none
    real*8, intent(in) :: a, b, c, lower_bound, upper_bound
    real*8 :: Q, R, theta, x, Au, Bu, thi
    integer :: i, iter
    real*8 :: two_pi       ! = 8 * atan (1.0d0)

    Q = (a**2 - 3.*b)/9.
    R = (2.*a**3 - 9.*a*b + 27.*c)/54.

    two_pi = 8 * atan (1.0d0)
    !If roots are all real, get root in range
    if (R**2 < Q**3) then
        iter = 0
        x = R/sqrt(Q**3)
        theta = acos(x)
        print *, "theta = ", theta, x
        do i=-1,1
            iter = iter+1
!!            x = -2.D0*sqrt(Q)* cos((theta + dble(i)*PI*2.D0)/3.D0) - a/3.D0
            thi = (theta + i*two_pi)/3.
            x   = -2.*sqrt(Q) * cos (thi) - a/3.
            !print *, "iter = ", iter, "root = ", x
            if ( (x >= lower_bound) .and. (x <= upper_bound) ) then
                find_roots = x
                print *, "find_roots = ", x
!                return
            end if
        end do
    !Otherwise, two imaginary roots and one real root, return real root
    else
        Au = -sign(1.D0, R)*(abs(R)+sqrt(R**2-Q**3))**(1.D0/3.D0)
        if (Au.eq.0.D0) then
            Bu = 0.D0
        else
            Bu = Q/Au
        end if
        find_roots = (Au+Bu)-a/3.D0
        return
    end if

 end function find_roots

 real*8 function get_cubic (x, a, b, c)
    implicit none
    real*8, intent(in) :: x, a, b, c
    get_cubic = ( ( x + a) * x + b ) * x + c
 end function get_cubic


! Now it turns out that it can be shown analytically that a cubic equation with the following inputs:
   real*8 Q0, alpha, dt, Y, a, b, c, lower_bound, upper_bound, val, fn
   real*8, external :: find_roots, get_cubic
!
    Q0    = 1.D0
    alpha = 1.0D-2
    dt    = 0.00001D0
    Y     = 1000000.0D0
!
    a = -(2.*Q0 + Y)
    b = -(alpha - Q0**2 - 2.*Y*Q0 + dt/2.*alpha)
    c = (dt/2.*alpha*Q0 + Y*alpha - Y*Q0**2)
    write (*,*) a,b,c
!
    lower_bound = Q0-sqrt(alpha)*1.1
    upper_bound = Q0+sqrt(alpha)*1.1
    write (*,*) lower_bound, upper_bound
!
    val = find_roots (a, b, c, lower_bound, upper_bound)
!
    fn = get_cubic ( val, a,b,c )
    write (*,*) val, fn
!
! Test the better root values
    val = 0.9d0
    fn = get_cubic ( val, a,b,c )
    write (*,*) val, fn
!
    val = 1.1d0
    fn = get_cubic ( val, a,b,c )
    write (*,*) val, fn
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this, I think you're right that the method just fails close to the acos(+-1) limits. My workaround will probably be to just check when the root should be very close to the limits and just output the limit itself in that case.